# Getting error while storing spark collection on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: S3

```
   spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","8888888888888888888")
   spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","AKIA2APTGNWJUHKOWU5Y,m93O4xLVomStGIwj932x+8lO8/")

     val config = Config(Map(
       "url" -> "******.database.windows.net",
       "databaseName" -> "UATShakeShackOlo",
       "queryCustom" -> "SELECT  * FROM dbo.Adjustment",
       "user" -> "***************",
       "password" -> "*************"

     ))

     val collection = spark.read.sqlDB(config)
     collection.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").save("S3://snowflakess/ShakeShack_POC/Customers.csv")
```

Comment: `s3` not capital.

Comment: Your key is exposed, so I recommend you to delete this question.

Comment: well, at least your secret isn't composed, but yes, roll your access key too.